# How can i check if atleast one option in all uniquely named checkboxes is checked?

Tags: jquery, html, validation, input, checkbox

How can i check using Jquery that from every uniquely named checkboxes group atleast one option is checked ?
These checkboxes are generated dynamically and total numbers of uniquely named checkboxes will vary...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_4[]" value="A">
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_4[]" value="B">
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_4[]" value="C">
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_4[]" value="D">

<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_5[]" value="A">
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_5[]" value="B">
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_5[]" value="C">
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_5[]" value="D">

<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_17[]" value="A">
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_17[]" value="B">
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_17[]" value="C">
<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_17[]" value="D">
```

So far, I have tried this:

```
$('input:checkbox[class=mcqcb][name*="ans_*"]').not(':checked').length
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: $('input:checkbox[class=mcqcb][name*="ans_*"]').not(':checked').length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the only way to do this with jQuery is to use an array to store the grouping data for the checkboxes:

JS:

```
var detectionArry={};
$('.mcqcb').each(function(){
    if (!detectionArry[$(this).attr("name")]){
    detectionArry[$(this).attr("name")]=$(this).prop("checked");
    }
});
for (var i in detectionArry){
    if (!detectionArry[i]){
     alert(i+" is not completed!");   
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65p9E/show) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/65p9E/)

**Edit:**
To keep it within checkboxes only just replace the selector (`$('.mcqcb')`) with the selector that you have provided: `$('input:checkbox[class=mcqcb]')`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/65p9E/3/show) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/65p9E/3/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/65p9E/  if i have a radio button with same class name it does not gives desired results as the radio input also has checked property !!!

Comment: Seems to be working fine with radio buttons as well.. http://jsfiddle.net/65p9E/1/ Unless you want the behavior to be seperate?

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="checkbox" class="mcqcb" name="ans_4[]" value="A" checked>`

jst put "checked" at in end of tag!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you right. But in case you want to test the size of checked checkboxes which name attribute starts with ans, you have to modify your selector like this:

```
$('input:checkbox[name*="ans_"]:checked');
```

In case you want to test if at least one of all these group has been checked it is fine. But if you want to test if at least one of each group has been checked you have to loop / filter:

```
function checkGroup() {
    var finalResult = true; 
        nameArr=[], 
        checkboxGroups = $('input:checkbox[name*="ans_"]');
    checkboxGroups.each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        if($.inArray(name, nameArr) == -1)
            nameArr.push(name);
    });
    // Go through each name attribue and make sure at least one is checked.
    $.each(nameArr, function(index, value){
        if($('[name="' + value + '"]:checked').length === 0){
           finalResult = false; 
        }
    });
    return  finalResult;   
}
```